# RoboVM: Change View

Tags: java, ios, xcode

How can I program a function to change the visible view? For Example: I click on a button, and then change the visible view to a second view. In xcode it looks like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W31TK.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a UIViewController and simply present it from your current.

This is your RootViewController in the IOSLauncher:

```
        rootViewController = UIApplication.getSharedApplication()
            .getKeyWindow().getRootViewController();
```

Then create a new one in code:

```
UIViewController controller = new UIViewController();
```

And then switch to it:

```
rootViewController.presentViewController(controller, true, null);
```

Comment: I try your code and it works, but what I must do to go back to rootcontroller? With controller.presentViewController(rootViewController, true, null); it works but when I repeate it (go to rootController and back to controller...), the app crash with a NSInvalidArgumentException?!

Comment: @Londi i had the same issue and solved it by calling `presenterViewController` inside `viewDidAppear`